# Factory reset problem in LG F160

Tags: applications

I have installed an English ROM in LG Optimus F160

So, the question is if I soft reset my phone will the installed rom be uninstalled or remain installed?

Answer (score 0):

The system ROM should remain on the device after a "soft" factory reset.

A normal factory reset only clears the user data, applications, and settings from the device. A factory reset does not remove the ROM or other data on the system partition.

Under most conditions the system ROM will usually only be removed when formatting the system partition in recovery mode or installing a new ROM.